# SQL - Find a specific date depending on condition from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables having schema as given below

```
EmployeeDetails - (employeeID,timestamp,status)
EmployeeActivity - (employeedID, timestamp, activity)
```

Status field is either 0 or 1

What I want to do is, find the timestamp when status goes from 1 to 0. Use this date as parameter in finding activity done after this date from table 2.

I am sorry I am not able to provide a sample query at this point. Since I am not sure whether this can be done using a single query or will I need PL/SQL.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

**EDIT**

Sample Data

Table 1

```
employeeID | timestamp | status
         1 | 01-NOV-13 |      1
         2 | 01-NOV-13 |      1
         1 | 02-NOV-13 |      0
         2 | 02-NOV-13 |      1
         1 | 03-NOV-13 |      0
         2 | 03-NOV-13 |      0
```

Table 2

```
employeeID | timestamp | activity
         1 | 01-NOV-13 |      1
         2 | 01-NOV-13 |      1
         1 | 02-NOV-13 |      0
         2 | 02-NOV-13 |      1
         1 | 03-NOV-13 |      1
         2 | 03-NOV-13 |      0
```

Result

```
employeeID | timestamp | activity
         1 | 03-NOV-13 |      1
```

This is the output since EmployeeId=1 has activity when its status is 0.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: OK. Provide some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Is it supposed to go from 1 to 0, or from 0 to 1? You wrote previously that from 0 to 1, and from your data one can see that the record was returned because the status for `employeeID` = 1 changed from 1 to 0. Could you _please_ write a detailed description of what the query is supposed to do, and all the conditions and what happens when there are multiple changes?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej - Sorry for the confusion. I have made the changes

Comment: If we concatenate all three fields in `Table 1` will we get a **unique key**?

Comment: @PM 77-1 I'm assuming that the primary key for both "EmployeeDetails" (Table 1) and "EmployeeActivity" (Table 2) tables is a concatenation of the two fields "employeeID" and "timestamp_val"

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH previous_statuses AS (
  SELECT employeeID,
         timestamp_val,
         status,
         LAG( status ) OVER ( PARTITION BY employeeID ORDER BY timestamp_val ) AS previous_status
  FROM   employeeDetails
),
changed_statuses AS (
  SELECT employeeID,
         timestamp_val
  FROM   previous_statuses
  WHERE  status = 0
  AND    previous_status = 1
)
SELECT a.employeeID,
       a.timestamp_val,
       a.activity
FROM   employeeActivity a
       INNER JOIN
       changed_statuses s
       ON (    a.employeeID = s.employeeID
           AND a.timestamp_val = s.timestamp_val);
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ceb42/1/0)

Comment: Can you please explain to me the "WITH previous_statuses AS" part of the query?

Comment: `WITH` just creates a named sub-query.

Comment: `LAG` is an analytic function that gets the previous row - in this case it gets the previous row ordered by timestamp for the same employee. See [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) for details on `LAG`. All the previous_statuses sub-query does is get the contents of the employeeDetails table but appends an additional column containing the status for previous entry in the table for that employee.